# Predict a future result of column based on other columns using LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm

I want to predict a future result of the column based on other columns using LSTM.
My Data Frame is time indexed and I have multiple columns including the Emergency column that I want to predict(Emergency column contain either ones or zeros) the problem is that I'm beginner in ML and I'd like a source code that has solved a similar problem to modify or some hints on how to start and thnx in advance

I have tried to predict the next 10 hours of the emergency column with only one feature but the predicted data was horrible and didn't match the real data at all

here's how my database looks like

```
Time             A     B     C     D      ...            Emergency                              
1/1/19           10    15    16    2      ...              0                
1/2/19           12    9     8     30     ...              0               
1/3/19           11    16    5     -2     ...               1
```

I want to predict the next days Emergency status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below architecture

[image: ![enter image description here]

- Number of columns (`A` to `Z` in the figure) excluding timestamp
  will be the sequence length of your LSTM.
- Add a fully connected NN layer at the output of the LSTM (`return_Sequence=False` in keras/tf)
- Use the features of the timestamp as additional features of the FC layer
- The features of the timestamp can be dayof the week, day of the month, the month of year, festival day, public holiday etc.
- The output size of the FC layer will be size `1` i.e a single probability score that predicts if it is an emergency or not.
- You can use the binary crossentropy loss to train the model.